# how to use Oracle stored function returning REF_CURSOR in Java/JDBC

Tags: java, oracle

I have following code, it does not work!! can you help me find out what is issue? I am using Oracle 11g.

```
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String getDBUSERCursorSql = "{? = call get_my_data(?,?)}";
    try {
        callableStatement = jdbcConn.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql);

        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        //--
        callableStatement.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(someDate.getTime()));
        callableStatement.setString(3, userId);

        // execute getDBUSERCursor store procedure
        callableStatement.executeQuery();

        // get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
        rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String userId = rs.getString("USER_ID");
            System.out.println("userId : " + userId);
        }
        ..
        ...
        ...
```

Following is the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00905: object SDB.GET_MY_DATA is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Here is stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_my_data (p_date   IN DATE,
                                    p_user_id       IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
 v_rc              SYS_REFCURSOR;
 BEGIN

     OPEN v_rc FOR
          SELECT *
            FROM user_logins
           WHERE login_date > p_date AND user_id = p_user_id
        ORDER BY created DESC;

  RETURN v_rc;
  END get_my_data;
  /
```

Comment: Define "does not work".  Compiler error? Runtime error? not the results you are expecting?

Comment: Edited with error message

Comment: The problem is inside the stored procedure itself. Sadly, the error message points to the beginning of the procedure, not to the exact problem location.

Comment: Stored function works fine when executed on plsql

Comment: Interesting. However ORA-06550 means "Invalid PL/SQL block", and PLS-00905 means "An invalid package specification or stored subprogram was referenced". I would try to recompile the stored procedure to see if it compiles cleanly or not. If you get errors, `show errors` would theoretically show the errors.

Comment: Hmm. Please check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13690282/357403

Comment: That is it!! now our db developer says.... some reason oracle marked function as invalid :)