# Returning cursor from function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

What I'd like to do is return results from function, so function could be used in following way:
`select * from stuff(1)`

Simplified function example:

```
FUNCTION stuff(p_var number) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS

CURSOR cur(cp_var number) IS
    SELECT * FROM dual ;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur(p_var);
    RETURN cur;
END stuff;
```

But this this doesn't compile:
`Error: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type`

Is it possible to return cursor/results from function, which is defined this way?

Comment: You cannot do this using a standalone function, you'll need to create a table type and a table function.  Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#ADDCI4680

Comment: `cur` is a `cursor` not a `sys_refcursor`. You need declare the variable as `cur sys_refcursor` and then use `open cur for select * from dual`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oracle version: 12c Standard Edition, 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function return sys\_refcursor call from sql with specific columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690110/function-return-sys-refcursor-call-from-sql-with-specific-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function is returning a `sys_refcursor` and in your code you are returning a `simple cursor`. This makes the code wrong. If you want to return a `ref_cursor` from a function you can use as below:

```
create or replace function stuff (p_var number)
   return sys_refcursor
is
   rf_cur   sys_refcursor;
begin
   open rf_cur for
      select *
        from employee
       where employee_id = p_var;

   return rf_cur;
end stuff;
```

Execution:

```
select stuff(1) from dual;
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't return rows and columns as may be expected. So you'll need to unpack returned result.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, your result set is a collection and then you need to unpack to see each column.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create pipe lined table function, here is an article which will help you.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot call ref cursors directly in FROM clause however you may try following..

SELECT * FROM TABLE(function_name());

Function should be with Return type as PLSQL Nested table
CREATE NESTED TABLE TYPE of CURSOR%ROWTYPE;