# Oracle Function Return a RecordSet

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle19c

Is it possible to define a function in Oracle 19c that returns a multi-row & column record set without resorting to a temporary tables (private or global) or custom types declared outside of the function?

I am fine with declaring a new type inside of the function but that doesn't seem like something Oracle supports.

```
create or replace 
  function get_employees() 
    return all_employees Is Table (
                                    employee_id number
                                   ,employee_name varchar(255)
                                  );
Begin
 Select employee_id, employee_name into all_employees from employees;
end;

Select * from all_employees();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40707655/returning-cursor-from-function-in-oracle

Comment: Thank you @Kurt. I have seen that chain of ideas. They don't meet my need/desire. I don't want a sys_ref cursor. I want all the rows not a single row at a time. What I want as the function return is all employees not a single employee. The other referenced answer doesn't meet my needs because it requires that I first create two custom types, an object and a table type. I don't want my custom types persisted in the schema. If my example above worked all_employees would be private to the function, created at start & automatically destroyed at the end.

Comment: If it's private to the function then how would any code outside that function know about it?

Comment: the only way I've ever done this, and it's been a few years so maybe there's something new I don't know about, is using a pipelined function (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829880/create-an-oracle-function-that-returns-a-table ), but you'll need to put your function in a package so the types can be defined alongside it

Comment: @Kurt I think I see your point. The return variable all_employees must be public. Is there still not a way to define the variable as a table as part of declaration of the function? I really do not want a custom all_employees type persistent in the database.

Comment: you can put the types and the function declaration together in a package. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829880/create-an-oracle-function-that-returns-a-table

Comment: @Kurt is there no way to do this without a package? A package presents other problems I would really like to avoid.

Comment: Not that I know of, but as I said it's been a while.  I can't think of any problem a package presents that a function doesn't also present.

Comment: Just like your previous question, this feels like an XY-problem. You want to solve a concrete problem but you are giving us a very restricted number of possible solutions for a highly abstracted sub-problem and have not described what the underlying problem is that you want to solve. The solution to the underlying problem is probably not to write a function and return a custom data-type but is going to be something else; but if we don't know what that underlying problem is then we can't easily help.

Comment: Thanks @Kurt I suspect you are right. This may be a fool's errand. I may have to accept that my database schema is going to get splattered with lots of custom types unless I am able to use a package. Absolutely amazed that Oracle makes this such a gigantic pain.

Comment: I don't see why you think packages are a pain.  They're really quite convenient for organizing related types, procedures, and functions together and keep your db very clean

Comment: Thanks again, @Kurt. My understanding is that packages are not permitted because they are not supported by all of the upstream third party applications that interact with the database. Perhaps this will force the issue though.

Comment: @KevinWhite I would definitely press the issue.  there's no fundamental difference between a standalone function and a packaged function.  If an application can call a function, it can also call a packaged function.

Answer (score 3):

Given the question:

> Is it possible to define a function in Oracle 19c that returns a multi-row & column record set without resorting to a temporary tables (private or global) or custom types declared outside of the function?

and

> I don't want a sys_refcursor.

Then the answer is "No".

If you eliminate all the possible solutions to the problem and ask "what else can be used to solve the problem" then the answer is that there is nothing else; you've already eliminated all the other solutions.

The options are:

- Don't use functions and just write the underlying query in SQL:

  ```sql
  Select employee_id, employee_name from employees;
  ```
- Create a view:

  ```sql
  CREATE VIEW all_employees (employee_id, employee_name) AS
    Select employee_id, employee_name from employees;
  ```
- From Oracle 19.7, you may be able to use an SQL table macro.

  ```sql
  CREATE FUNCTION get_all_employees RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN q'{SELECT employee_id, employee_name FROM employees}';
  END;
  /

  SELECT * FROM get_all_employees();
  ```

  *(But that is effectively just writing a reusable macro that the SQL engine will rewrite into selecting from the underlying table.)*
- Use one of the options you have rejected. Either: a cursor; globally-defined types and a `PIPELINED` function; globally-defined types and a non-`PIPELINED` function; or a private temporary table.

Comment: SQL macros were backported to 19c so they may be a viable option depending on the exact version of the database.

Comment: @JonHeller Thanks, updated with the minor version required and an example.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to define a function in Oracle 19c that returns a multi-row & column record set without resorting to a temporary tables (private or global) or custom types declared outside of the function?

Yes, return a cursor.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_employees() 
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor FOR
    Select employee_id, employee_name from employees;

  RETURN v_cursor;
END;
/
```

Then you can process it using:

- PL/SQL;
- a third-party language; or,
- SQL*Plus or SQL Developer with the `PRINT` command:

  ```sql
  VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

  BEGIN
    :cur := get_employees();
  END;
  /

  PRINT :cur;
  ```

Comment: I don't think your example will meet my needs because it cannot be called like a table "Select * from all_employees();"